# Good books/resources on OMG Data distribution service?

Tags: data-distribution-service

I want to understand how exactly the OMG Data distribution service works and how it can be used for real time inter process communication with better performance.Please suggest me the best resources/books? i tried with Google and YouTube but could not able to get the exact DDS functionality related information and DDS implementation in real time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Data Distribution Service Portal at the OMG contains several tutorials contributed by the different vendors. See http://portals.omg.org/dds/tutorials these can be good references as they tend to focus on the standard features and less on vendor-specific details.

That said several of the vendors have created excellent tutorials. In addition to the one mentioned in the previous post I like the one by Twin Oaks Computing. The whole tutorial fits in one (long) HTML page with nice concept and figures:  http://www.twinoakscomputing.com/coredx/dds_tour

For more in depth coverage I like the eLearning program from RTI (the company where I work)  http://www.rti.com/elearning/index.html

Two of the modules that are available for free provide very good intro material on concepts and design patterns:

Introduction -- http://vimeo.com/user14186439/review/57448029/6138f1e5c1
Instances Samples and Data-Types -- http://vimeo.com/user14186439/review/61771143/d59ca69515

Also I would recommend the Case+Code (use-case) examples in the RTI Community Portal. They provide complete code examples illustrating how the different DDS APIs and QoS can be use to meet realistic use-cases. See  http://community.rti.com/case-and-code

Gerardo

Answer (score 1):

No books that I know of, but I like this paper...

http://www.slideshare.net/Angelo.Corsaro/the-data-distribution-service-tutorial

It guides you through some of the features of DDS and how you could utilize them by referring to a temperature sensor example.

If you want something more hands-on, there is an Open Source implementation of DDS at

http://www.prismtech.com/opensplice/opensplice-dds-community

which contains a set of examples and a lot of other documentation about the features and API.

Thanks
James